# How do I deploy to firebase functions without npm dependency conflict?

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I am trying to deploy an angular universal project. When I run npm run build:ssr it compiles correctly. I am able to run the emulators without any issue. But when I try to deploy with `firebase deploy` I get the error

```
=== Deploying to 'terabulkssr2'...

i  deploying functions, hosting
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  artifactregistry: ensuring required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled...
+  artifactregistry: required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled
+  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
+  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: preparing codebase default for deployment
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged C:\Users\Fujitsu\terabulk\terabulk-front-ssr\dist\functions (14.54 MB) for uploading
+  functions: functions folder uploaded successfully
i  hosting[terabulkssr2]: beginning deploy...
i  hosting[terabulkssr2]: found 335 files in functions
+  hosting[terabulkssr2]: file upload complete
i  functions: updating Node.js 16 function ngssr(us-central1)...
Build failed: npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: @nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader@8.2.6
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@14.1.3
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"^14.1.3" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@"^14.0.0 || ^15.0.0" from @angular/cdk@14.1.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/cdk
npm ERR!     @angular/cdk@"^14.1.2" from the root project
npm ERR!   18 more (@angular/fire, @angular/forms, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^8.2.0" from @nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader@8.2.6
npm ERR! node_modules/@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader
npm ERR!   @nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader@"^8.2.6" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/common@8.2.14
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@"^8.2.0" from @nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader@8.2.6
npm ERR!   node_modules/@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader
npm ERR!     @nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader@"^8.2.6" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See /www-data-home/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /www-data-home/.npm/_logs/2022-08-20T16_19_35_316Z-debug-0.log; Error ID: beaf8772

Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
        ngssr(us-central1)
i  functions: cleaning up build files...

Error: There was an error deploying functions
```

I want to know how to force this to work because it works locally. I try `firebase deploy --force` and still doesn't work

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try run this:

```bash
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
npm audit fix --force
firebase deploy
```

Note, you can also use `firebase deploy --only hosting`